# How to connect locally hosted MySQL database with the docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Through `docker-compose.yml` I am able to run the application. Now we want to move the application to production, But we don't want to use the container database. So is there any way so that I can connect my local MySQL database with the application using `docker-compose`?

My docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - app-db

  app-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app-db/Dockerfile

    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=Optimize
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Instead of `app-db` part I just want to connect to my locally hosted `mysql` database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Find the host machine ip in the docker network. If you use docker-compose.yml `version: "3"` it's probably that that IP is: `172.18.0.1`, **but confirm it** searching for the "Gateway" of your container (your host):

```
docker inspect <container-id-or-name> | grep Gateway
"Gateway": "",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
```

So inside your docker application point to MySQL as this: `172.18.0.1:3306` (maybe in a configuration file). Take into account that that IP is fixed as long as the docker network still the same (the network is created by docker-compose, and it is not removed unless you do `docker-compose down`)

Also, check that your MySQL is listening to all of its interfaces. In your `my.cnf` search for `bind-address` that should be `0.0.0.0` (consider security issues if your server has public IP).

---

As an alternative you can bring to the container the same networking as your host, in order to share the localhost, so the container will find mysql there. Use network mode as "host":

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - 8080:8080
    network_mode: "host"
```

Then, point in your `hibernate.properties` to mysql as this: `localhost:3306`

Comment: I got 
`docker inspect <container-id-or-name> | grep Gateway

"Gateway": "",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",`
but once i compose, i got this in [log file](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/03b87968283c2207fdb4cdf4544d91b7)

Comment: Do you know where is the config file of your app? To update it accordingly

Comment: you mean web applications `hibernate.properties` file?

Comment: Maybe! Do you see the host of mysql there? Try putting 172.19.0.1 and port 3306, that is the IP of your host from docker standpoint

Comment: in that file i changed `jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/optimize1` to `jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://172.19.0.1:3306/optimize1` but still its not able to connect. Its showing same in the logs as wel

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: I can't realize what is happening. You have an alternative that is using the `network_mode: host` in the service of you docker-compose.yml. So the container gets the same localhost as your host, so you can point to to mysql as `localhost:3306`

Comment: can you explain me little bit more. How to add this?

Comment: Nope still the same problem. Is there any thing wrong with my web-app's [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/e2b7cac28d76ebf3a0714e17ef3f16e4)

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks ok. I thing that you need to realize the specific error. The logs don't give enough information

Comment: it just says `Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: Is it your mysql up and running? Check your my.cnf whether it has a `skip-networking` config, should not have it. Check the 3306 port is open

Comment: Nope it doesn't have. I have also used `bind-address= 0.0.0.0` in `my.cnf` file

Comment: What a blunder mistake i did. After making all the changes in `docker-compose.yml` and `hibernate.properties` **i forgot to remove the existing application war file and building war file again**. After doing from the beginning i am able to use my local DB. Thanks man. And i completely ** apologize ** for such lengthy conversations.

Comment: @Ben.Bean that kind of things always happend to all of us. Happy to hear that. You're welcome!

Comment: In docker-compose.yml, is there a way to do "inside your docker application point to MySQL as this ..."?  If not, what other technique could be used to make the application container independent of the MYSQL connection details? Somehow create another container that acts as a proxy to the actual database? I'm not sure how to make this convenient for both local development and remote deployment. I don't understand all that must be done to change from using a mysql container db, to using mysql on host pc (windows). I understand the IP issue; I just don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: Above docker-compose script worked for me. Thanks !!  network_mode: "host"

Comment: I added network mode "host" to my web app and it worked, thanks

Comment: It worked with network mode "host", but it doesn't allow port mapping

Comment: ```network_mode: "host",``` that's what worked for me https://gist.github.com/rintoug/3c7ad792064b622faf062c823d0fc4d2

Answer (score 149):

Just use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

To make it work on Linux, you just need to start your Docker container passing the parameter `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`

Comment: You just saved my life! I love you. This should be the accepted answer, or added to the accepted answer for all to know!

Comment: @Júlio Falbo: At which point exactly can I use "host.docker.internal" instead of "localhost"? Could you elaborate a little? Thank you!!

Comment: Sure. In your client application. In the case above we can use it in the db configurations of the `web-app`, so, instead of `localhost` we use `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Why this is not working for me? If I ping from inside a container I saw "host not found"

Comment: @JúlioFalbo changed localhost to host.docker.internal in my app's settings but I get the following Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'host.docker.internal' (-2)"). I am using docker version 1.20. what could be the issue?

Comment: @PhilipMutua, If you are using Linux, you just need to start your Docker container passing the paraneter `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`.

Comment: Just to clarify, i set env variable `PGHOST: host.docker.internal` for my expressjs server in docker-compose. It was `localhost` before, and this fixed the `ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: Also you should have docker version 20.10+ (works on 20.10.12). 
In docker-compose you can use
`extra_hosts:
   - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
`

Comment: in my case,

    docker run -d --restart always --name vaultwarden \
      --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
      -e DATABASE_URL=mysql://admin:*******@host.docker.internal:3600/vault \
      -v /vw-data/:/data/ \
      -p 8082:80 \
      vaultwarden/server:latest 

this is my docker command. but I'm still getting this error, 

    [CAUSE] BadConnection(
        "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.docker.internal' (115)",
    )

Comment: On MacOS you maybe wanna use docker.for.mac.host.internal as the hostname

Answer (score 9):

Allow permission using mysqld.cnf

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

save your file and restart mysql server

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

login to Mysql

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
EXIT;
```

Find your IP

```
ip addr show
```

And use it in your docker container 192.168.x.x

Comment: Which IP I need to use in the application to use localhost database, Is it Docker one or system IP  
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:45:20:4f:98:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 5988sec preferred_lft 5988sec
    inet6 fe80::c273:df61:8eff:65a1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: This is in the local machine. But the question was how to do this using docker container

Answer (score 9):

If anybody is using **mac os** then please use `docker.for.mac.host.internal` instead of `host.docker.internal` as the environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

The easist way is use `host.docker.internal` instead `localhost`.

```
MONGO_SERVER = {
'host': 'host.docker.internal',
'port': 27017,
'username': 'admin',
'password': '123456'}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

We had a same scenario where we wanted to setup a Development local machine setup for the services where a developer can just make `docker-compose up -d` and use all the latest dev builds in his local machine.

But we started facing issues while connecting our tomcat based web service configured as service in the `docker-compose.yml` to `**mysql-8.0**` service within the docker-compose. So as alternative and quick fix we thought to use local mysql configured on the local laptop with Ubuntu and docker-compose.

Our tomcat-application was using a `application-dev.yml` file with jdbc config variable to connect to the mysql, say something like

```
    url: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/abcDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: abcderf
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
      db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcd
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcd
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=abcdDB
        volumes: 
          - ./sql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
      
      frontend:
        container_name: frontend
        image: abc/abc:frontend-1.1.36
        depends_on:
          - backend

      nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.19-alpine
        links:
          - "frontend"
          - "backend"
        volumes:
          - ./proxyConf:/etc/nginx/conf.d 
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
      backend:
        container_name: backend
        image: abc/abc:server-3.1.161
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: .env
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=devtest
          - DB_HOST=db:3306
          - DB_NAME=abcDB
        depends_on:
          - db
```

**Solution worked for us:**
As we wanted to connect our docker-compose tomcat service from the local mysql we tried the below routes.

`docker inspect <container-id-or-name> | grep Gateway` which returned the ip Gateway ip value as`

```
"Gateway": "",
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
        "IPv6Gateway": ""
```

used the above Ip in the `application-dev.yml` as below ( URL post resolve of the `${DB_HOST}` looks something as below But the IP changes to next highrt post the `docker-compose down` ex: 172.19.0.1)

```
    url: jdbc:mysql://172.18.0.1:3306/abcDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: abcderf
```

Modified **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
      frontend:
        container_name: frontend
        image: abc/abc:frontend-1.1.36
        depends_on:
          - backend

      nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.19-alpine
        links:
          - "frontend"
          - "backend"
        volumes:
          - ./proxyConf:/etc/nginx/conf.d 
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
      backend:
        container_name: backend
        image: abc/abc:server-3.1.161
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: .env
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=devtest
          - DB_HOST=172.18.0.1:3306
          - DB_NAME=abcDB
        depends_on:
          - db
```

and Also updated the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and from the mysql command line allow the `root` user to connect from any Ip.

Below were the only commands worked for **mysql-8.0** as other were failing with error `syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'abcd'' at line 1`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
```

Restart the mysql client

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me by adding `network_mode` in `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  aservice:
    image: image:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8787:8787"
    # Allow docker to connect to localhost
    network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score -3):

locally I had MySQL running on port 3306 and MySQL container running on the same port 3306

You have to be sure that MySQL or whatever database service that you are using in your container is stopped in your local envirmint before connecting to it

In my case, I had MySQL running through Homebrew

```
brew services stop mysql
```