# Trying to connect Jira (docker) to Mysql (non docker) 5.6.44 but have Connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, jdbc, database-connection, jira

I'm trying to configure jira on a CentOS 7 virtual machine.
I managed to launch Jira's docker image without any problems with a docker-compose :

```
 jira:
    image: 'cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:latest'
    container_name: jira
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
    volumes:
      - '/var/atlassian/jira:/var/atlassian/jira'
```

I also installed mySQL on my virtual machine (without using a docker) while following the installation procedure described here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/connecting-jira-applications-to-mysql-5-6-938846854.html

Including :

```
CREATE DATABASE jiradb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
CREATE USER 'jiradbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON jiradb.* TO 'jiradbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
flush privileges;
```

MySQL is accessible on my localhost port 3306 (the command telnet 0.0.0.0 3306 answers me well)

I also downloaded the 5.1.38 connector-j from MySQL and since I didn't have a lib folder in my /var/atlassian/jira, I created it with a mkdir and unzipped the jar in it.

I restart Jira with:

```
docker-compose stop jira
docker-compose rm jira
docker-compose start jira
```

Now, I go on my browser to the jira software address, at the time of the Database setup, I entered this information :

```
Database Connection: My Own Database 
Database Type: MySQL 5.6
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
Database: jiradb
Username: jiradbuser
Password: secret
```

When I click on "Test Connection", it doesn't work. The answer is :

```
Error connecting to database

Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The log of jira when I click on "Test Connection" is below :

```
==> atlassian-jira.log <==
2019-07-19 14:42:37,906 http-nio-8080-exec-21 ERROR anonymous 882x13x1 b45eq1 10.107.135.18,172.18.0.3 /secure/SetupDatabase!connectionCheck.jspa [c.a.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager] Could not successfully test your database:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
  ... 3 filtered
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
  at com.atlassian.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.getTestDatabaseConnection(DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.java:347)
  at com.atlassian.jira.config.database.JdbcDatasource.getConnection(JdbcDatasource.java:211)
  at com.atlassian.jira.config.database.DatabaseConfig.testConnection(DatabaseConfig.java:88)
  at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.setup.SetupDatabase.testConnection(SetupDatabase.java:230)
  at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.setup.SetupDatabase.doValidation(SetupDatabase.java:194)
  at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.setup.SetupDatabase.doConnectionCheck(SetupDatabase.java:126)
  ... 3 filtered
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at webwork.util.InjectionUtils$DefaultInjectionImpl.invoke(InjectionUtils.java:70)
  at webwork.util.InjectionUtils.invoke(InjectionUtils.java:56)
  ... 2 filtered
  at com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:63)
  ... 7 filtered
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
  ... 49 filtered
  at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66)
  ... 1 filtered
  at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64)
  ... 31 filtered
  at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30)
  ... 24 filtered
  at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25)
  ... 25 filtered
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
  ... 175 more
```

Is there anything I'm not doing right?

Thank you in advance.

Hugo

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you for your answer. The `network_mode: "host"` didn't work for me because I also use Traefik. But you put me on the right track and this outcome helped me: [How to connect locally hosted MySQL database with the docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543842/how-to-connect-locally-hosted-mysql-database-with-the-docker-container)
The solution to my problem was to use this command :

```
docker inspect <container-id-or-name> | grep Gateway
"Gateway": "",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
```

And use 172.18.0.1 instead of "localhost" for the "host" field of my local mySQL database

Answer (score 3):

Mysql database is running on host (non-docker) at port 3306.

While Jira is running inside container. By-default container runs in [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) networking mode, where container network is different from host network. Hence localhost inside container is not the same as on host.

Here you can do two things:

- In your Jira container refer to mysql database using `private/public-ip:3306`

OR

- Run Jira docker container in [host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) networking mode, so that localhost inside container is same as that on host. Because in this mode container uses network of host.

```
 jira:
    image: 'cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:latest'
    container_name: jira
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
    volumes:
      - '/var/atlassian/jira:/var/atlassian/jira'
    network_mode: "host"
```

**NOTE:** `network_mode: "host"` option will tell docker container to use [host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) networking mode.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` in the connection url in the `dbconfig.xml` file. In the Dockerfile I have the following lines:

```
EXPOSE 3306
VOLUME ["/var/atlassian/application-data/jira"]
```

I hope it helps