# Connecting to the host MySQL database from the Docker container

Tags: docker

I am packaging my application and trying to deploy it on my server.

I have a database already installed and running on my server, MySQL, and I have my Express Node.js app that wants to communicate with this database.

The Express app will work inside a Docker container, the Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM node:20-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3001
CMD npm install && npm run build && npm run start
```

This is my `.env` file that I use to read the environment variables from:

```bash
DATABASE_HOST= "localhost" # string ex: localhost | ip
DATABASE_PORT= 3306 # number
DATABASE_NAME= "mydatabase" # string
DATABASE_USERNAME= "myuser" # string
DATABASE_PASSWORD= "mypassword" # string
```

I use `docker compose` to run my Docker container, because I have frontend:

```bash
$ docker compose up
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  webadmin:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
```

Comment: And presumably this _doesn't_ work - what's the problem you're facing? `DMA_DATABASE_HOST` isn't going to be `localhost` inside the Compose network, even if that `.env` file _is_ inside the container (is it?) Why not put the appropriate configuration in the Compose file? Also the `Dockerifle` for your Express app seems very bad, do you really want to reinstall dependencies and rebuild every time the container restarts (hint: no)?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I am really noob in Docker, and my system is still under development, so I only want it to work, although, yes I believe it's pretty simple docker files

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes the .env file is inside the container

Comment: It really shouldn't be, even if it _did_ contain the right values. Externalise configuration, don't bake it into the image.

Comment: Actually I was thinking the same, but I have no good experience in Docker, for instance I'm not sure if I should ignore the docker files in `.gitignore` then if they will have secret credentials

Comment: You can pass an env file _via Compose_: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/. Also read: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md. Fundamentally it's still unclear what your current problem actually is, but I think you have a lot of rework to do that might fix it in the meantime - I'd suggest deleting until then. A basic Dockerfile for a Node.js app will probably look something like this: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/main/Dockerfile (note use of multi-stage build and layering that leverages the cache).

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I put the environment variables inside the docker-compose file for the backend, what will be the value of the `DATABASE_HOST`? is it localhost or is it something else? the database is on the host machine outside the container

Comment: Research it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24319662/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44543842/3001761, ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made it with the following edits to my `.env` file, first, the host I set to my public server IP address:

```bash
HOST= "96.xxx.xxx.xxx" // the public ip
```

and the database host is localhost:

```bash
DATABASE_HOST= "localhost"
```

and in the `docker-compose` file, I made use of the `network_mode` option:

```yaml
services:
  webadmin:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    network_mode: host  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
```

Now, from the perspective of the API container, localhost is like saying localhost on the server itself, the host machine.

Now it works, and my API service can communicate with the database, and is now public to the internet.

Comment: Host networking won't work if Docker Desktop is in use; it means the `ports:` option for `api` can't be used (you can't choose a different host port or choose not to publish the port at all); and you won't be able to connect to `webadmin` as a host name.

Comment: @DavidMaze But I don't use docker desktop