# error on connecting mysql hosted locally

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I restored mysql dump and can be accessed in my terminal (I need to issue `sudo mysql` to access this db or even to start mysql) :

[image]

I know this is privilege issue. But when I call mysql in python program, I get this error:

```
   OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I tried both ways supplying password and keeping it blank.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

replace '`localhost`' by `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885164/pymysql-cant-connect-to-mysql-on-localhost

Comment: OMG, switching to 127.0.0.1 from localhost fixes.