# google-collab: How to connect to pymysql in Google Collab?

Tags: python, mysql, google-colaboratory, pymysql

In google-colab, I tried this:

```
!pip install pymysql
import pymysql
cnx = {'host':'localhost','username':'root','pwd':'','db':'test'}
connection = pymysql.connect(cnx['host'], cnx['username'], cnx['pwd'], cnx['db'])
connection.close()
```

Error faced:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
    582                                 (self.host, self.port), self.connect_timeout,
--> 583                                 **kwargs)
    584                             break

5 frames
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
    628                 exc.traceback = traceback.format_exc()
    629                 if DEBUG: print(exc.traceback)
--> 630                 raise exc
    631 
    632             # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Tried the suggestion of `127.0.0.1`, but no luck and then seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14351678/5320982), tried:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(cnx['host'], cnx['username'], cnx['pwd'], cnx['db'],port=3306)
```

Still same `connection refused`. Is it even possible to connect to local database from google-colab? If so, what is the error else what option do I have ?

Database details(running from `XAMPP`):

```
MySQL Version                 : 10.1.13-MariaDB
Host                          : localhost
User                          : root
Port                          : 3306
Server Default Charset        : latin1
```

Status of `my.ini` file: `bind-address="127.0.0.1"` and password is commented out in the file `# password       = your_password`. In SQLYog databse is running.

Comment: Can I get the endpoint(like it is available in aws db) of this mysql database somehow ?