# PyMySQL using localhost vs socket incoherant behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql

I am using [PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io) to connect to a database running on localhost. I can access the database just fine using the username/password combiunation in both the command line and [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) so the database does not appear to be the probem here.

My code is as follow. However, when *using the `host="127.0.0.1"` options, I get an `OperationalError` and an `Errno 111`.* Using the same code, but connecting via the socket Mariadb runs on is fine.

```
import pymysql.cursors
from pprint import pprint


# This causes an OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")   
# connection = pymysql.connect(
#     host="127.0.0.1",
#     port=3306,
#     user="root",
#     password="S3kr37",
#     db="my_test",
#     )

# This works.
connection = pymysql.connect(
    user="root",
    password="S3kr37",
    db="my_test",
    unix_socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
    )

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "select * from MySuperTable"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        pprint(results)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

PS: Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885164/pymysql-cant-connect-to-mysql-on-localhost) has the same problem but the solution offered is the socket. ***That is no good enough***: I want to know ***why*** I cannot use the hostname as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errorcode 2003 (CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR) is returned by the client library, in case the client wasn't able to establish a tcp connection to the server.

First you should check, if you can connect via telnet or mysql command line client to your server.
If not, check the server configuration file:

- does the server run on port 3306?
- is IPv4 disabled?
- is skip-networking enabled?
- is bind-address activated (with another IP?

Comment: `bind-address` was the problem. Urgh. Thank you.

Comment: While telnet localhost:3306 tries to connect to 127.0.0.1, mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 tries to connect via unix socket (opposite to -h127.0.0.1). So I don't believe that you tried to connect via telnet.