# Can't connect python server and mysql with Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-python

I am newly learning Docker and compose, I have searched and watched many tutorials but could not understand what is causing this connection error:

_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)

my file structure:
docker-compose.yml
.env
mysql/
database.sql
Dockerfile
python/
server.py
Dockerfile

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mysql:
    build: 
      context: ./mysql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

  pythonapp:
    build:
      context: ./python
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

python/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

RUN pip install mysql-connector-python && \
    pip install python-dotenv

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "-u", "server.py"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

mysql/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY ./database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

python/server.py:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import mysql.connector
import json
import os 

load_dotenv('../.env')

# Establish connection to MySQL
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user=os.getenv('MYSQL_USER'), 
    password=os.getenv('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'), 
    host=os.getenv('_HOST'),
    port=3306,
    database=os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'))
print("DB connected")
...
```

.env:

```
_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

found this: [PyMySQL can't connect to MySQL on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885164/pymysql-cant-connect-to-mysql-on-localhost)
and:

I have tried _HOST=127.0.0.1, _HOST=mysql, _HOST=host.docker.internal
but the error did not change.
Also tried to compose for second time to solve connection maybe because the database was not ready for connection, but getting the same error.
So the MySQL database is running but the python server does not connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `localhost` is always wrong host for the db when using docker compose like this. `localhost` points to the localhost of the *python* container, not to the localhost of your *host* machine. You need to refer to it with the service name `mysql`.

```
_HOST=mysql
```

Then, in addition to the answer by Leo Aso, you might need to wait until the MYSQL service is healthy and can be connected to. The `depends_on` alone is not enough, and it will try to connect to the DB before it is ready. This works for me

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
        timeout: 20s
        retries: 10

  pythonapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
```

I added a `healthcheck` to the `mysql` service and `condition: serivce_healthy` to the python service, so that it will not start until `mysql` is reporting healthy.

### Bonus: How to debug

If it's still not working, first verify that you can connect to the db at all even inside the `mysql` container, by running this command:

```
docker compose exec -it mysql mysql -ppassword
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know there was a `healthcheck`, it solved all the problem, so it was happening because the server was starting before the mysql connection established.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `load_dotenv('../.env')`, but your `.env` file only exists locally; there is no such file inside the Docker container.

You will have to find a way to get it there somehow. The easiest way would be to move the `.env` file inside the Python folder, then `COPY` it in your `Dockerfile`, and use `load_dotenv('./.env')` in your code.

Comment: it seems kind of working, but I am still facing: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)
also when I try mysql instead of localhost: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql:3306' (111)